# Recurrence relations (finding the solution)

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k \geq 2$.

$x_k=\frac{2}{3}x_{k-1}+\frac{1}{3}x_{k-2}$

$x_0=0$

$x_1=1$

How to find the solution for $\lbrace x_k \rbrace _{k \in \mathbb{N_0}}$?

Since it's for $k \geq 2$ I got:

$k=2:$

$x_2=\frac{2}{3}x_1+\frac{1}{3}x_0=\frac{2}{3}$

But how to continue to find the solution? I thought about using induction and I get as result:

$x_{k+1}= \frac{2}{3}x_k+\frac{1}{3}x_{k-1}$

Here I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$
x_k=\frac{2}{3}x_{k-1}+\frac{1}{3}y_{k-1}\\
y_k = x_{k-1}
$$
so
$$
\left(x_k \atop y_k \right)=\left({\frac23 \quad \frac13 } \atop {1 \quad 0 } \right) \left(x_{k-1} \atop y_{k-1} \right)
$$
which gives you 
$$
\left(x_k \atop y_k \right)=\left({\frac23 \quad \frac13 } \atop {1 \quad 0 } \right)^k \left(x_{0} \atop x_1 \right)
$$
So you need the powers of the matrix which can be found by eigenvalues. They are $1$ and $ - \frac13$. So you can as well make the ansatz

$$
x_k = a + b (-\frac13)^k
$$
solving for $a$ and $b$ gives 
$$
0 = x_0 = a + b \\
1 = x_1 = a + -\frac{b}{3}
$$
So 
$$
x_k = \frac34 (1 - (-\frac13)^k)
$$

Comment: +1. It make sense to write it as a system of equations because the theory is well developed for solving a system of first order difference equations. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk8Q0pd5G1s) for all the steps.